# When voting for US president are signatures always compared by a volunteer to previous signature on record? Is there any training for this?

Tags: united-states, voting, voting-systems, voter-registration

**updates:**

- Politico 2020-10-23 [Pennsylvania Supreme Court says ballots can’t be rejected based on signature comparisons](https://www.politico.com/news/2020/10/23/pennsylvania-court-ballot-signatures-431794)
- Los Angeles Times 2020-10-28 [‘Ripe for error’: Ballot signature verification is flawed — and a big factor in the election](https://www.latimes.com/california/story/2020-10-28/2020-election-voter-signature-verification)

> When performed by professionals in criminal cases or legal proceedings, signature verification can take hours. **But election employees in many states must do the job in as little as five seconds.** [...] **In 2016, mismatched signatures were the most common reason that mail ballots were rejected, according to federal officials.** With record numbers of people voting by mail this cycle, ballots thrown out for signature problems and other issues have the potential to decide races where the margin of victory is slim.

That's the last one, I won't add any further updates.

---

NPR.org's [More Than 550,000 Primary Absentee Ballots Rejected In 2020, Far Outpacing 2016](https://www.npr.org/2020/08/22/904693468/more-than-550-000-primary-absentee-ballots-rejected-in-2020-far-outpacing-2016) mentions:

> Most absentee or mail-in ballots are rejected because required signatures are missing **or don't match the one on record**, or because the ballot arrives too late.

In the US is signature matching done for most or all mail-in ballots? Is it also done for in-person voting? Is it judged simply by any random volunteer, or only by someone "skilled in the art"? Is the same person who checks the signature also the one who counts the vote, or is signature rejection vote-agnostic?

Comment: Question could be much cleaner and clearer, if you would confine it to just one or two questions, as it is, you have asked six questions.

Comment: @BobE in this particular case there is one underlying issue and trying to stretch this out over several or even six different question posts would be counterproductive as it would lead to fragmented answers, duplication and even questions closed as duplicates (which often happens when a posted question is *answered* elsewhere even if the the question is not exactly the same). Based on experience asking several thousand SE questions I've decided that for this topic it's best to keep it all in one place. Six seaprate question posts would not the way to go here.

Comment: Wouldn't comparing signatures violate the rights of people who don't draw their signature the same way each time?

Comment: @endolith that's a real problem, and in mail-in voting there is no way to find out one's signature is being challenged and to have a chance to try once more.

Comment: @endolith - violate the rights ??  To exercise the franchise, there are certain statutory requirements to be fulfilled, one requirement maybe to provide a signature. It is a reasonable expectation that an effort will be made on the part of the voter to duplicate one's registration signature. If my ballot is signed "Daffy Duck" but I registered as "Donald Duck", why should I expect my ballot to be accepted?

Comment: Then why not confine your question to one state?  Because different states have different regulations or statutes, there is no way to give a concise answer that will apply to all jurisdictions in the US. (Or were you intending to limit the question to elections for US president ?)

Comment: @BobE endolith said *draw* their signature the same way each time, not *spell* their signature the same way each time.

Comment: @uhoh see https://www.douglas.co.us/elections/voter-service-and-polling-centers/ballot-discrepancy-faq/  for example of how to "cure" defective signature.  Also addresses "draw"

Comment: @BobE There may be a requirement to *provide* a signature, but there's no implication that the signature has to be drawn exactly the same way every time.  Mine certainly never is.  Invalidating citizens' votes because they don't draw their signature in a certain way certainly sounds like a violation of their voting rights to me. I've seen a ballot measure disqualified because of mismatching signatures, and it was proven that the people in question really had signed the petition, for instance. I doubt most people realize that the drawing of their signature is ever going to be scrutinized.

Comment: @endolith see https://www.sos.state.co.us/pubs/elections/docs/SignatureVerificationGuide.pdf  There is no requirement that the signature be drawn exactly the same way every time, that is not the intent of checking signature matches. Rather the intent of signature matching is to ensure that the election process takes reasonable steps to ensure that the ballot being presented is actually originating with a qualified elector. People who don't think that their signature on a ballot authentication envelope will be scrutinized haven't thought out "why do I need to sign anyway"

Comment: @BobE "Why do I need to sign anyway" You need to sign for legal reasons, not identification reasons.

Comment: [Pa. lawsuit challenges signature verification of mail-in ballots](https://www.lehighvalleylive.com/elections/2020/08/pa-lawsuit-challenges-signature-verification-of-mail-in-ballots.html)  "More than 26,000 of those ballots were rejected, the suit said, including for "signature-related errors or matters of penmanship."  

Comment: @endolith - "legal reasons"  can you be more specific?

Comment: @endolith - more interesting to read the actual complaint and the requested relief seems to boil down to:  1) opportunity to "cure" allegedly deficient signatures, 2) institution of uniform written standards for signature verification procedures.  PA would do well the emulate processes employed in Colorado (and others).

Comment: @BobE https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature#Function_and_types

Comment: @endolith. Complaint found at https://campaignlegal.org/sites/default/files/2020-08/File%20Stamped%20PA%20Complaint.pdf, .... BTW, complaint doesn't attempt to quantify the number of mis-matched signatures.... your wiki reference doesn't explain your "legal reasons" - can you be more specific?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd need to go state-by-state to see exactly how each state handles their elections.  Different states may well do things differently.

In general, however, signature matching is something that is done for absentee ballots not for in person ballots.  Generally, the signature appears on an inner envelope on a ballot that is mailed in.  The election official examines that outer envelope to verify the postmark (showing that the ballot was mailed in before the deadline) along with the signature (showing that the ballot was completed by the voter).  If everything checks out, the envelope is opened and the actual ballot inside is taken out and counted.  If not, the ballot is set aside.

Ballots are essentially never counted by a human so the person examining the signature would never count a ballot.  It would generally be a different person that fed the ballot into the counting machine.  One issue that does come up is that knowing a person's name and where they are registered, you can often make a pretty good guess about how that person is voting.  If someone has a stereotypically African American name and is registered to vote in Detroit, for example, you can reasonably infer that their vote will likely be for Biden.

The amount of training that someone examining signatures would receive will depend heavily on the state and what you mean by "skilled in the art".  It is unlikely that any state is going to have, say, forensic handwriting analysts comparing millions of mail-in ballots (and that ignores those that criticize handwriting analysis as junk science).  Plus, you only have a handful of known signature to compare against where someone appearing in court as an expert witness would generally review a much larger sample of known signatures.  So verifying the signature is bound to be at least somewhat subjective.

Comment: U said: "In general, however, signature matching is something that is done for absentee ballots not for in person ballots"  I can't speak for any states other than PA and Ohio. In the past, in both states, **when I voted in person** my signature was compared with my registration signature as well as the signature I used at the last election.

Comment: I think that you have confused the envelopes. For absentee and mail-in-ballots there are **two** envelopes. The outer envelope, bearing a postmark, does not have a signature. The inner envelope (that does not have any postage or postmark) bears the validation or authentication information, part of which is the signature.

Comment: while I agree that there is certainly some subjectivity to validation of signatures, You are potentially incorrect when you say that the team of election employees have only one signature to compare against. In Ohio, as an example, the authentication of signatures is done by a team of two, one R & one D, additionally these teams have at their disposal digital images of the voter's driver's license, which carries a signature, as well as prior signatures used for voting.  Lastly, the election officials in Denver, insist that their teams have been trained for this by the FBI.

Comment: @BobE - You're right, I did mean to say inner ballot.  That's fixed.  And I changed "one" to "a handful" (depending on whether the voter has a license and has voted in the past in that juristiction).  It's still much less than a handwriting expert would want (and that assumes you believe that handwriting analysis is a valid scientific endeavor).  And they spend much less time than a handwriting expert would spend.

Comment: Overall, I agree with your response that  the correct answerS lies in an analysis of each states practices.  Unfortunately, the poster has asked several questions which will tend to defy a simple answer.

Comment: @BobE In MA we don't have to sign anything when voting in person. You tell the poll worker your name and address, and they cross out your line on the voter roll. There's no proof of identity, this just prevents the same name being used to vote twice.

Comment: I've had to sign in when voting in MI.  But there was no attempt to do any sort of verification of the signature.  You had to provide an ID so they did check the photo against the person in front of them and the address against the address they had on file.

Comment: @Barmar:   MA doesn't seem to ask for signatures, however according to MA SOS there are 4 conditions whereby a person voting in person may be asked to provide identification. [https://www.sec.state.ma.us/ele/elevotingprocess/votingprocessidx.htm]

Comment: @JustinCave- You signed in, your signature is also on your photo ID, do you suspect that if the signatures were grossly different that the poll worker would question that, just as they would question you if your registration address did not match your photo ID address. It's obvious that different jurisdictions have differing requirement, which makes providing a concise answer to the original question difficult !

Comment: @BobE - Is it possible?  Sure, I suppose (though I'd expect the poll monitors to object if someone objected).  But it's not part of the official process, not every ID would have a signature, and poll workers get a couple hours of training at most-- not nearly enough to do any sort of meaningful handwriting analysis.

Comment: @BobE - I think your URL has an issue-- I assume you mean https://www.michigan.gov/documents/SOS_ED_2_CHALLENGERS_77017_7.pdf  The word "signature" appears only once in that document and refers to a poll watcher's identification card.

Comment: correct (bad brackets !).  The document appears to give broad ( "but reasonable") authority to the challenger. I assume that among the documents that a challenger might consider is gross inconsistency with an offered proof of ID and the voter present. For example, black man who offers his photo ID - that of a  white female. Or a voter who offers his signature as Tommy Jones, but produces an ID that says Sammy Sneed. That's the point of having challengers - to reasonably insure that the voter is who he says he is.  A voter ought to be able to reasonably duplicate his official signature.

Comment: @BobE - Is it possible?  Sure.  But if the picture matches and the address matches and the poll watcher isn't allowed to touch the ID to see the rather small signature and the challenger has no training in signature analysis, it's tough to form a reasonable belief that the voter is invalid based on the signature.  If the photo doesn't match or the address is wrong, that can produce a challenge.  But the question is about the normal process not something that might happen in some exceptional corner case.

Comment: Actually I thought the question was really about absentee and mail-in votes, I confess that I have gone off on a tangent commenting on your statement about signatures not being "checked" for in-person voting. All I can say is that, by actual experience, in-person signatures **are checked** in Ohio and used to be checked in PA. That MI is different is not particularly surprising ( and I don't mean that in any negative connotation) BTW, this is what I meant when I suggested early on that the Q was too broad. Good night, stay safe

Comment: Signature matching is done for in person voting in New York.  @BobE what if the Ohio voter has no driver's license?

Comment: @Phoog re: Ohio, state issued ID, military ID, current utility bill, bank statement, social security card, SSID, if all else can cast provisional ballot, then prove eligibility within 7 days.

Comment: @BobE many of those have no signature to verify.

Comment: @phoog - Sure, a recent bank statement has no signature, but (I think) the statement is used to identify the person and address of the potential voter. As I recollect the signature match is between the voter registration signature and the person signing the poll book, rather than a three way match (contemporaneous signature, identity document and registration)

Comment: @phoog, the thing that becomes very clear is the diversity among states (and perhaps even within states) on the practices (rules & regs). One would think that the Federal government would have the capability to establish universal standards of how  **federal elections** are to be conducted.

Comment: @BobE but it does have that capability.  For example, it sets standards for the enfranchisement of US citizens who reside abroad.  That it hasn't set standards for voter identification doesn't imply that it can't. Anyway, my original comment was in reaction to "additionally these teams have at their disposal digital images of the voter's driver's license," not in reference to documents presented by the voter.

Comment: @phoog, I am told that election workers that are validating mailed in votes in Ohio have access to Drivers lic. (the whole lic, not just the driver's pix).  Anyway, my comment about national standards was really in reference to the mechanics of voting. Example: some states process mail ballot on arrival, some wait to begin the processing till 7am on election day. Some states require voter identification on the outer envelope, other on the inner envelope... etc etc

Comment: @JustinCave just fyi I've added one more news item to the question. It doesn't change the question nor affect your answer, but you might find that it adds additional context.

Answer (score 2):

Confining my answer to just the title question (s):

> ... are signatures always compared by a volunteer to previous signature on record?

a) not necessarily a volunteer, more often than not the team doing the signature comparisons are paid. That said, yes, the signatures are compared with other on-record signatures of the same person.

> Is there any training for this?

Yes, however the requirement for training likely varies between jurisdictions.

ETA: [Colorado Signature Verification Guide](https://www.sos.state.co.us/pubs/elections/docs/SignatureVerificationGuide.pdf)

Comment: Just fyi I've added one more news item to the question. It doesn't change the question nor affect your answer, but you might find that it adds additional context.